# Fill missing date for each group and impute empty values in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime

For the following dataframe, how can I fill missing date for each group `city` and `district`, let's say full date range is from `2019/1/1` to `2019/6/1`, then fill empty `value`s with `mean`s before and after cells, if there are no values before or after it, then use `bfill` or `ffill`.

```
   city district      date  value
0     a        d  2019/1/1   9.99
1     a        d  2019/2/1  10.66
2     a        d  2019/3/1  10.56
3     a        d  2019/4/1  10.06
4     a        d  2019/5/1  10.69
5     a        d  2019/6/1  10.77
6     b        e  2019/1/1   9.72
7     b        e  2019/2/1   9.72
8     b        e  2019/4/1   9.78
9     b        e  2019/5/1   9.76
10    b        e  2019/6/1   9.66
11    c        f  2019/4/1   9.57
12    c        f  2019/5/1   9.47
13    c        f  2019/6/1   9.39
```

The expected result will like this:

```
   city district      date  value
0     a        d  2019/1/1   9.99
1     a        d  2019/2/1  10.66
2     a        d  2019/3/1  10.56
3     a        d  2019/4/1  10.06
4     a        d  2019/5/1  10.69
5     a        d  2019/6/1  10.77
6     b        e  2019/1/1   9.72
7     b        e  2019/2/1   9.72
8     b        e  2019/3/1   9.75
9     b        e  2019/4/1   9.78
10    b        e  2019/5/1   9.76
11    b        e  2019/6/1   9.66
12    c        f  2019/1/1   9.57
13    c        f  2019/2/1   9.57
14    c        f  2019/3/1   9.57
15    c        f  2019/4/1   9.57
16    c        f  2019/5/1   9.47
17    c        f  2019/6/1   9.39
```

How can I do that in Pandas? Thanks a lot.

**Update:**
When I add `freq = 'M'`, all become `NaN`s.

```
df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
( df.set_index('date')
  .groupby(['city','district'],as_index=False)
  .apply(lambda x: x.reindex(pd.date_range(df.date.min(),df.date.max(), freq = 'M'))
                    .interpolate()
                    .bfill()
                    .ffill())
  .rename_axis(index = [0,'date'])
  .reset_index()
  .drop(0,axis=1)
)
```

Output:

```
         date  city  district  value
0  2019-01-31   NaN       NaN    NaN
1  2019-02-28   NaN       NaN    NaN
2  2019-03-31   NaN       NaN    NaN
3  2019-04-30   NaN       NaN    NaN
4  2019-05-31   NaN       NaN    NaN
5  2019-01-31   NaN       NaN    NaN
6  2019-02-28   NaN       NaN    NaN
7  2019-03-31   NaN       NaN    NaN
8  2019-04-30   NaN       NaN    NaN
9  2019-05-31   NaN       NaN    NaN
10 2019-01-31   NaN       NaN    NaN
11 2019-02-28   NaN       NaN    NaN
12 2019-03-31   NaN       NaN    NaN
13 2019-04-30   NaN       NaN    NaN
14 2019-05-31   NaN       NaN    NaN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your solution with replace misisng values per groups for avoid wrong replacement if some only `NaN`s values per group:

```
df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

rng = pd.date_range('2019-01-01', '2019-06-01', freq='MS')
c = df['city'].unique()
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([c, rng], names=['city', 'date'])

df1 = (df.set_index(['city', 'date']).reindex(mux, method='ffill')
       .groupby(level=0)
       .apply(lambda x: x.bfill().ffill())
       .reset_index())
print (df1)
   city       date district  value
0     a 2019-01-01        d   9.99
1     a 2019-02-01        d  10.66
2     a 2019-03-01        d  10.56
3     a 2019-04-01        d  10.06
4     a 2019-05-01        d  10.69
5     a 2019-06-01        d  10.77
6     b 2019-01-01        e   9.72
7     b 2019-02-01        e   9.72
8     b 2019-03-01        e   9.72
9     b 2019-04-01        e   9.78
10    b 2019-05-01        e   9.76
11    b 2019-06-01        e   9.66
12    c 2019-01-01        e   9.66
13    c 2019-02-01        e   9.66
14    c 2019-03-01        e   9.66
15    c 2019-04-01        f   9.57
16    c 2019-05-01        f   9.47
17    c 2019-06-01        f   9.39
```

Or use custom function with `reindex` and `method='bfill'`:

```
df2 = (df.set_index('date')
         .groupby(['city','district'], group_keys=False)
         .apply(lambda x: x.reindex(pd.date_range(df.date.min(),df.date.max(), freq='MS'), method='bfill')
                           .ffill())
         .rename_axis('date')
         .reset_index())
print (df2)
         date city district  value
0  2019-01-01    a        d   9.99
1  2019-02-01    a        d  10.66
2  2019-03-01    a        d  10.56
3  2019-04-01    a        d  10.06
4  2019-05-01    a        d  10.69
5  2019-06-01    a        d  10.77
6  2019-01-01    b        e   9.72
7  2019-02-01    b        e   9.72
8  2019-03-01    b        e   9.78
9  2019-04-01    b        e   9.78
10 2019-05-01    b        e   9.76
11 2019-06-01    b        e   9.66
12 2019-01-01    c        f   9.57
13 2019-02-01    c        f   9.57
14 2019-03-01    c        f   9.57
15 2019-04-01    c        f   9.57
16 2019-05-01    c        f   9.47
17 2019-06-01    c        f   9.39
```

Solution with `interpolate`:

```
df2 = (df.set_index('date')
         .groupby(['city','district'], group_keys=False)
         .apply(lambda x: x.reindex(pd.date_range(df.date.min(),df.date.max(), freq='MS'))
                           .interpolate()
                           .bfill()
                           .ffill())
         .rename_axis('date')
         .reset_index())
print (df2)
         date city district  value
0  2019-01-01    a        d   9.99
1  2019-02-01    a        d  10.66
2  2019-03-01    a        d  10.56
3  2019-04-01    a        d  10.06
4  2019-05-01    a        d  10.69
5  2019-06-01    a        d  10.77
6  2019-01-01    b        e   9.72
7  2019-02-01    b        e   9.72
8  2019-03-01    b        e   9.75
9  2019-04-01    b        e   9.78
10 2019-05-01    b        e   9.76
11 2019-06-01    b        e   9.66
12 2019-01-01    c        f   9.57
13 2019-02-01    c        f   9.57
14 2019-03-01    c        f   9.57
15 2019-04-01    c        f   9.57
16 2019-05-01    c        f   9.47
17 2019-06-01    c        f   9.39
```

EDIT1: Solution only for one column:

```
df2 = (df.set_index('date')
         .groupby(['city','district'])['value']
         .apply(lambda x: x.reindex(pd.date_range(df.date.min(),df.date.max(), freq='MS'))
                           .interpolate()
                           .bfill()
                           .ffill())
         .rename_axis(['city','district','date'])
         .reset_index())
print (df2)
   city district       date  value
0     a        d 2019-01-01   9.99
1     a        d 2019-02-01  10.66
2     a        d 2019-03-01  10.56
3     a        d 2019-04-01  10.06
4     a        d 2019-05-01  10.69
5     a        d 2019-06-01  10.77
6     b        e 2019-01-01   9.72
7     b        e 2019-02-01   9.72
8     b        e 2019-03-01   9.75
9     b        e 2019-04-01   9.78
10    b        e 2019-05-01   9.76
11    b        e 2019-06-01   9.66
12    c        f 2019-01-01   9.57
13    c        f 2019-02-01   9.57
14    c        f 2019-03-01   9.57
15    c        f 2019-04-01   9.57
16    c        f 2019-05-01   9.47
17    c        f 2019-06-01   9.39
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, in your second solution, is it possible add `.interpolate()`?

Comment: @ahbon - yes, only is necessary remove `method` parameter in `reindex` for missing values

Comment: Another question, if I want use `apply` and `lambda` functions to only `value1` column, if `df` has other columns `value2, value3, value4, ect.` I have tried with `df.set_index('date')
         .groupby(['city','district'], group_keys=False)['value1']
         .apply(lambda x: x.reindex(pd.date_range(df.date.min(),df.date.max(), freq='MS'), method='bfill')
                           .ffill())
         .rename_axis('date')
         .reset_index()`. It doesn't work.

Comment: @ahbon - Solution was edited for processing only one column `value`. all another columns are removed in output.

Comment: I have 100k entries data, it works slow with code above, is it possible to improve?

Comment: @ahbon  not so easy. I think first should be fastest, but there is no interpolate. It is slow because a lot of operations per groups, unfortunately

Comment: OK, if I remove `interpolate`, maybe it will be quick?

Comment: @ahbon - hard question, the best test. btw, for each group is same start and end `datetime`s ? So possible specify it like `rng = pd.date_range('2019-01-01', '2019-06-01', freq='MS')` ?

Comment: Great, this is much quicker.

Answer (score 2):

We could do:

```
df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df['date'],format ='%YYYY/%dd/%mm' )
```

---

```
( df.set_index('date')
  .groupby(['city','district'],as_index=False)
  .apply(lambda x: x.reindex(pd.date_range(df.date.min(),df.date.max()))
                    .interpolate()
                    .bfill()
                    .ffill())
  .rename_axis(index = [0,'date'])
  .reset_index()
  .drop(0,axis=1)

)
```

---

**Output**

```
                  date city district  value
0  2019-01-01 00:01:00    a        d   9.99
1  2019-01-02 00:01:00    a        d  10.66
2  2019-01-03 00:01:00    a        d  10.56
3  2019-01-04 00:01:00    a        d  10.06
4  2019-01-05 00:01:00    a        d  10.69
5  2019-01-06 00:01:00    a        d  10.77
6  2019-01-01 00:01:00    b        e   9.72
7  2019-01-02 00:01:00    b        e   9.72
8  2019-01-03 00:01:00    b        e   9.75
9  2019-01-04 00:01:00    b        e   9.78
10 2019-01-05 00:01:00    b        e   9.76
11 2019-01-06 00:01:00    b        e   9.66
12 2019-01-01 00:01:00    c        f   9.57
13 2019-01-02 00:01:00    c        f   9.57
14 2019-01-03 00:01:00    c        f   9.57
15 2019-01-04 00:01:00    c        f   9.57
16 2019-01-05 00:01:00    c        f   9.47
17 2019-01-06 00:01:00    c        f   9.39
```

Comment: Could you please add output?

Comment: Can we use `( df.set_index('date')
  .groupby(['city','district'],as_index=False)['value']
  .apply(lambda x: x.reindex(pd.date_range(df.date.min(),df.date.max()))
                    .interpolate()
                    .bfill()
                    .ffill())
  .rename_axis(index = [0,'date'])
  .reset_index()
  .drop(0,axis=1)
)`? My real data have more than `value` column, it become all `NaN`s after apply your code.

Comment: Sorry, just noticed one issue, my expected date increased by month, but your output inscreased by date.

Answer (score 0):

This solution:

```
df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

rng = pd.date_range('2019-01-01', '2019-06-01', freq='MS')
c = df['city'].unique()
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([c, rng], names=['city', 'date'])


print(df.set_index(['city', 'date']).reindex(mux).groupby(level=0)\
        .bfill()\
        .ffill()\
        .reset_index())
```

Output:

```
   city       date district  value
0     a 2019-01-01        d   9.99
1     a 2019-02-01        d  10.66
2     a 2019-03-01        d  10.56
3     a 2019-04-01        d  10.06
4     a 2019-05-01        d  10.69
5     a 2019-06-01        d  10.77
6     b 2019-01-01        e   9.72
7     b 2019-02-01        e   9.72
8     b 2019-03-01        e   9.78
9     b 2019-04-01        e   9.78
10    b 2019-05-01        e   9.76
11    b 2019-06-01        e   9.66
12    c 2019-01-01        f   9.57
13    c 2019-02-01        f   9.57
14    c 2019-03-01        f   9.57
15    c 2019-04-01        f   9.57
16    c 2019-05-01        f   9.47
17    c 2019-06-01        f   9.39
```